# Losing superfish menu item after logging out from administration panel

Tags: routes, navigation

I have a superfish menu as my nav menu bar. I customised it and added some pages for each menu item.

When I log out of the administration panel, as a general user I can only see the first menu item, all other menu items are gone.

[edit below]

Right, found out that the problem was because my other three menu items are all link to '.../add/node'. Superfish will not show empty links on the menu bar. However, I actually don't want some of the items link to anywhere as they all have submenu items. I want the link to remain empty so that the user can click on the submenu item. How can I achieve this?

Comment: checkout out your permissions. Admin user can access/view everything.

Comment: Hi, I have assigned permission to all for Menu(Administer menus and menu items) in 'People -> Permission', I also have cleared cache, but nothing has changed. Is there anything else I should assign?

Comment: can you see the menu items without superfish? try to create a custom menu from `admin/structure/menu` then assign the menu with superfish block `admin/structure/block` and see if you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an item in a menu tree is unavailable because of a lack of permissions, the entire tree below that item will disappear.

You should probably restructure your menu to use placeholders. Have a look at the [Special menu items](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module.